# Performing Vector Affine transformation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinates, affine-transformation

Due to incorrect datum coordinates, I need to move a large number of elements in shapefiles by a specific distance.

In QGIS 2.8 I would have used the "Affine Transformation" tool, but this does not appear to be available in QGIS 3.6.

Is there another tool or process I can use?

Answer (score 4):

There's also the GRASS tool `v.transform` (in the processing toolbox), which

> Performs an affine transformation on a vector layer.

Make sure you're running the QGIS version that says "with GRASS" in the name, otherwise you'll get an error message when trying to run a GRASS tool.

Note: I found this tool by searching the processing toolbox for the term "*affine*." The processing toolbox searchbar is a great place to go when you have a question along the lines of

- "Is there a tool that does *this thing*?" or
- "Where's the tool that used to be called *this name*?" or
- "Where's the *this name* tool that used to be in the *that name* menu?"

Comment: Thanks, this worked fine.

Comment: I tried using GRASS processing tools such as this one through QGIS on Mac for a while now but still unsuccessfully... A number of questions are open on this issue. In QGIS I can translate (move x,y) and rotate with the relevant tools, but I'm stuck at scaling the data: is there a native tool to scale a vector layer?

Comment: According to the original asker (Peter Cornelissen), *both* of the answers to this question worked for him. But if neither solution works for you, by all means post a new question.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the **Translate** tool from the *Processing Toolbox*:

> This algorithm moves the geometries within a layer, by offsetting them with a specified x and y displacement.

Comment: This worked fine too, but didn't need GRASS.

Comment: @PeterCornelissen - Most welcome, glad it helped :)